# Picklist not displaying values from controller

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to display a picklist based on values of a soql query in my controller. However the picklist is not working- it is not showing any values. What am I doing wrong here?

Vf page snippet:

```html
<apex:outputLabel value="VENDOR Name :"/>
    
<apex:selectList size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!vendorAccountNames}"/>
</apex:selectList><br/><br/>
```

Controller snippet:

```java
public List<SelectOption> vendorAccountNames {get;set;}
recordtype rt = [select id from recordtype where name = 'Vendor'];
public void getProjectNames(){
    vendorAccountNames = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<Account> projects = [
        SELECT  Id,Name FROM Account where recordtypeid = :rt.id
    ];
    
    for( Account acc : projects ) {
        vendorAccountNames.add( new SelectOption( acc.Id, acc.Name ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you actually call `getProjectNames()` somewhere in your controller? If not, then there'd be no values to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having to directly call the method through the controller like sfdcfox mentioned in his response, you could change the method from `void` to `List<SelectOption>`, rename to `getVendorAccountNames`, declare `vendorAccountNames` inside the method itself instead of outside, and return `vendorAccountNames` in order to take advantage of [Visualforce Getter Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_controller_getter_methods.htm).

Controller:

```
public List<SelectOption> getVendorAccountNames() {
    List<SelectOption> vendorAccountNames = new List<SelectOption>();
    for (Account acc : [SELECT  Id, Name FROM Account WHERE RecordType.Name = 'Vendor']) {
        vendorAccountNames.add(new SelectOption(acc.Id, acc.Name));
    }
    return vendorAccountNames;
}
```